# Inverse problem that involves derivatives of unknown function

Tags: inference, variational-inference

I am trying to solve an inverse problem where I try to approximate a function $f(x)$ that fulfills the following equation

$\ddot{z}_m = \frac{\sigma^2}{2} \frac{\partial^2 f(z_m)}{\partial z^2} + \frac{\partial f(z_m)}{\partial z} f(z_m).$

$z_m$ is a smooth deterministic trajectory that I know in functional form, so I can compute its time derivatives. However the equation involves both the unknown function $f$ and its 1st and 2nd spatial derivative so it is not clear to me if the problem is even solvable in this form.

For background, this equation comes from a variational problem where $z_m$ is the minimiser of a Lagrangian $L(\dot{z},z)$ if $f(x)$ is known.

Here I attempt to solve the inverse problem of trying to identify $f(x)$ in a case where I know the minimiser $z_m$.

The trajectory $z_m$ is extracted from my data and is approximated in a functional form, so I can compute time derivatives. So essentially I can sample N points from $z_m$ and create a system of equations from the equality. My issue is whether an equality that involves both the function and its derivatives is reasonable to use for function approximation.

I am currently try to impose a Basis function assumption, so that the derivatives are directly computable from the derivatives of the basis.

Any pointer on whether this problem is even solvable would help.

Comment: (just so you know, this isn't what statisticians mean when we say "variational inference"). Can you help clarify, why won't a standard differential equation solver work?

Comment: Thank you! Yes you are right this is not variational inference, just a variational problem. The unknown here is $f(x)$, while the trajectory $z_m(t)$ and its derivatives are known. 
So I am not sure how to apply the diff. eq. solver on this problem.

Comment: How is this a statistical problem?  Do you have any data?  A probability model?

Comment: @whuber Yes I have. The trajectory $z_m(t)$ is extracted from my data and is approximated in a functional form, so I can compute time derivatives. 
So essentially I can sample $N$ points from $z_m(t)$ and create a system of equations from the equality I wrote above.

Comment: Please provide details in your question.  Without them it will be impossible to know how best to proceed.